# Troubleshoot Windows Server 2003 ICS

Tags: windows

I had a machine running 2003 and the power suppy went out and took the motherboard with it. I was able to salvage the disk drives and bring it back up on new hardware.

The problem is that I can't get ICS to work now.

After many hours I finally got the other machines on the network to see the server and mount shares.  DNS is working, but none of the machines behind the server can connect to anything on the internet.

The server isn't passing anything through.

I've tried everything I can think of and can't get it to work again.

Comment: How is the Internet connection made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I assume Windows is seeing a new NIC?  I bet the registry still has ICS enabled on the old NIC but you can't see it in any GUI.  I'd google ways to find that NIC in regedit, or ICS settings in regedit, or maybe you can still see the old NIC by enabling "show hidden devices" in Device Manager.  Once you get rid of the old ICS settings/NIC then hopefully it'll work on the new NIC.